# Get index of series where value is True

Tags: python, pandas

How do I select only True values?

```
myindex=['a', 'b', 'c' , 'd']
myseries=pd.Series([True, True, False, True], index=myindex)

a     True
b     True
c    False
d     True
dtype: bool
```

What I have tried:

```
myseries.where(myseries == True)
```

This includes "c" while I need to return a list of a, b and d

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you just want to return the index which is a, b, c, d in your case use the `index` attribute:

```
myindex=['a', 'b', 'c' , 'd']
myseries=pd.Series([True, True, False, True], index=myindex)

a     True
b     True
c    False
d     True
dtype: bool

myseries[myseries].index
>> Index(['a', 'b', 'd'], dtype='object')
```

If you want it as a list:

```
myseries[myseries].index.tolist()
>> ['a', 'b', 'd']
```

Answer (score 4):

The code `myseries[myseries]` returns

```
a    True
b    True
d    True
dtype: bool
```

If you specifically want a list of ['a', 'b', 'd'] then you can it by `list(myseries[myseries].index)`.

Answer (score 4):

Fix your code

```
myseries.where(myseries).dropna().index
Index(['a', 'b', 'd'], dtype='object')
```

Answer (score 4):

Filter index values by `Series`:

```
print (myseries.index[myseries].tolist())
['a', 'b', 'd']
```

If performance is important convert both to numpy array and then filter:

```
print (myseries.index.values[myseries.values].tolist())
['a', 'b', 'd']
```

**Performance**:

```
np.random.seed(456)

myindex=np.random.randint(100, size=10000).astype(str)
myseries=pd.Series(np.random.choice([True, False], size=10000), index=myindex)
print (myseries)

In [7]: %timeit (myseries.index[myseries].tolist())
178 µs ± 5.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [8]: %timeit (myseries.index.values[myseries.values].tolist())
113 µs ± 762 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Another answers:

```
In [9]: %timeit myseries[myseries].index.tolist()
456 µs ± 28 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [10]: %timeit myseries.where(myseries).dropna().index
1.14 ms ± 28.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [11]: %timeit list(myseries[myseries].index)
886 µs ± 54.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [12]: %timeit [i for i,j in myseries.items() if j==True]
2.13 ms ± 8.36 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `list-comrehension` for it

```
import pandas as pd 

myindex=['a', 'b', 'c' , 'd']
myseries=pd.Series([True, True, False, True], index=myindex)
vals = [i for i,j in myseries.items() if j==True]
print(vals)
```

Output:

```
 ['a', 'b', 'd']
```